# How to view log of crash pod of a deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I know I can view logs of a crash pod by using
kubectl logs  --previous

But if a pod belongs to a deployment, when it crashes, a new pod with a different name is going to be created.

I can no longer know the crashed pod name.

Where can I find the log of the crashed pod?

And how can I  know if/when/why the pod crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Deployment-managed Pod crashes, the same Pod will restart, and you can look at its logs using `kubectl logs --previous` the same as before.

If you manually `kubectl delete pod` something a Deployment manages, you'll lose its logs and the Deployment will create a new one; but you have to explicitly do that, if a pod fails it will be the same pod restarting (or in `CrashLoopBackOff` state).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the logs then try the below command to know the reason why the pod is failed to start

```
kubectl describe pod  <pod-name>
```